# Getting the SMTP address for all Display Names in a Distribution Group when there is a Special Character in the Display Name

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2013

So, I'm back with more questions about getting the Distribution Group SMTP addresses for the Accepted Senders, ModeratedBy and the ManagedBy.

So the script I've got, works almost perfectly. However, when I pull the list of smtp addresses from the acceptmessagesonlyfromsendorsormembers using the display name, it works unless there is a special character in the name or additional spaces. So the display name format is "Last, First", and as long as the formatting follows that rule, we're fine. However if the last name has a space in it such as "Mac Gruber, Steven" or "#IT-Dept" it doesn't grab the SMTP address.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the Split logic I'm using to get the display name from the list of canonical names that are listed in the acceptmessagesonlyfromsendersormembers property.

For reference the script is below.

```
$props = @(
    "DisplayName"
    "SamAccountName"
    "PrimarySmtpAddress"
    @{n='Accepted Senders';e= {($_.acceptmessagesonlyfromsendersormembers | Foreach-Object {
    (Get-AdUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Split('/')][-1])'" -Property ProxyAddresses |
        Select-Object -Expand ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP:'}) -replace '^SMTP:'}) -join '; '}}
    "ModerationEnabled"
    @{N="ModeratedBy";E= {($_.ModeratedBy | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-AdUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Split("/")[-1])'" -Property ProxyAddresses |
        Select-Object -Expand ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP:'}) -replace '^SMTP:'}) -join '; '}}
    @{Name="Internal Senders Only";E={$_.RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled}}
    @{N="ManagedBy";E= {($_.ManagedBy | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-AdUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Split("/")[-1])'" -Property ProxyAddresses |
        Select-Object -Expand ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP:'}) -replace '^SMTP:'}) -join '; '}}
        )
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object $props -First 1000 | export-Csv x:\xxx.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated.

Ryan

Comment: So I guess the real question is... why are you trying to parse the DisplayName out of the DistinguishedName when `Get-ADUser` accepts a DistinguishedName for the `-identity` parameter so you don't even need to use `-filter`, it's just `Get-ADUser $_ -property ProxyAddresses`

Comment: Okay, tried to update using the method you suggested and it's not returning any email addresses for the accepted senders, managedby or moderatedby. For reference here is what I've updated to. I can't copy the whole thing so I'm only putting what I changed from the Accepted Senders $prop

`@{
    n="Accepted Senders"
    e={($_.acceptmessagesonlyfromsendersormembers | Foreach-Object {
    (Get-AdUser $_ -property ProxyAddresses |
        Select -Expand ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP:'}) -replace '^SMTP:'}) -join ';'}
}`

Comment: My apologies, it's not the DistinguishedName that is output it's a CanonicalName and Get-ADUser does not accept a CN from what I can determine.  Also, I can't seem to filter by it either. If you have a way to do so that'd be awesome.

Comment: Edited post to reflect CN instead of DN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is that your cmdlet is outputting CanonicalName, which is a calculated property and not something actually stored in AD. With a little help from JRV's answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e33dfd0-02e2-4855-96f6-56577c31b83f/moving-multiple-users-to-a-different-ou-using-canonical-name?forum=winserverpowershell), we have a function that will convert CanonicalName to DistinguishedName. DN can be passed to `Get-ADUser` directly, which simplifies things. First, the function, slightly modified to accept piped input nicely:

```
Function Convert-CanonicalName{   
    Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
            [string[]]$CanonicalName
    )
BEGIN{
    Try{
        $NameTranslate = New-Object -ComObject NameTranslate
        [void]$NameTranslate.GetType().InvokeMember('Init', 'InvokeMethod', $NULL, $NameTranslate, @(3, 2))
    }
    Catch{
        Throw $_
    }
}
PROCESS{
    ForEach($User in $CanonicalName){
        Try{
            [void]$NameTranslate.GetType().InvokeMember('Set', 'InvokeMethod', $NULL, $NameTranslate, @(8,$User))
            $NameTranslate.GetType().InvokeMember('Get', 'InvokeMethod', $NULL, $NameTranslate, @(1))
        }
        Catch{
            Throw $_
        }
    }
}
}
```

That allows us to pipe something like `'MyDomain.Net/Users/Big Jimmy'` into the function and have it return `'CN=Big Jimmy,OU=Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=Net'` to the pipeline.

Moving on, let's take one of your calculated properties:

```
@{n='Accepted Senders';e= {($_.acceptmessagesonlyfromsendersormembers | Foreach-Object {
(Get-AdUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.Split('/')][-1])'" -Property ProxyAddresses |
    Select-Object -Expand ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP:'}) -replace '^SMTP:'}) -join '; '}}
```

Now, we don't actually need the `ForEach-Object` loop in there. Everything here will take an array of things and process each item and pass it down the pipeline appropriately. So I'm going to drop that, and just for ease of reading I'm going to put each part of the pipeline on its own line. What we'll do is take the CanonicalNames output from `$_.acceptmessagesonlyfromsendersormembers`, pipe it to our new function which converts them to DNs, pipe that into `Get-ADUser`, expand the property, filter for SMTP, clean up the strings, and join them.

```
@{n='Accepted Senders';e= {($_.acceptmessagesonlyfromsendersormembers | 
    Convert-CanonicalName |
    Get-AdUser -Property ProxyAddresses |
    Select-Object -Expand ProxyAddresses | 
    Where-Object {$_ -cmatch '^SMTP:'}) -replace '^SMTP:' -join '; '}}
```

You should be able to modify your other items similarly with the same results. Admittedly I don't have an Exchange server to test against, but if you're getting an array of CNs then this should do the job.

Comment: That worked very well! However, I have a question that maybe you can assist with. We're currently using Get-ADUser to pull the SMTP addresses for each of the users in acceptedsenders list. However, there are times when the group itself is an accepted sender. When this happens we don't get the SMTP address for the user because they're not an AD User, just an emailed enabled object. Can you think of anyway to get the SMTP address for those as well? We're trying to work with mail-recipient instead of Get-ADUser but it's not cooperating. lol

Comment: There's always `Get-ADObject -Property ProxyAddresses`, which you can also pipe a DN to just like `Get-ADUser`. That'll find both DLs and Users, problem solved.

Comment: So, we have the solution, switchign to Get-ADObject solved the final problem. I wanted to note that we also found a secondary solution that achieved the same results. I'm including it here for reference.

`@{Name = 'Accepted Senders'; Expression = {($_.acceptmessagesonlyfromsendersormembers | Foreach-Object {(Get-Recipient -Identity ($_ -split $separator)[-1] | Select primarySMTPaddress).primarysmtpaddress}) -join ','}},`  The separator referenced was actually " domain.com"